# Is it safer to inject an EVENT scoped bean into a CONVERSATION/SESSION scoped bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, seam

Is it safe to inject beans from narrower scope into a wide scoped bean?

Does Seam CDI take care of it to figure out current EVENT/REQUEST/PAGE context to do the right injection into SESSION/CONVERSATION bean.

My point is. I don't want one page/even's objects getting mixed up with other page/event's data.

I can always use Component.getInstance() within the method to make sure I get current event/page's beans anyway. But I would like to use **@In(scope = ScopeType.EVENT)** even for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session and page scoped components are synchronized per default. Therefore, it should be safe to inject an event-scoped component, such as `EntityManager`, into them. As it is synchronized, two request won't interfere with two different injected objects.

To be completely sure, that you don't run into concurrency problems, I recommend that you don't inject these components but fetch them from the component repository:

```
MyComponent myComponent = (MyComponent) Component.getInstance("myComponent");
```

Comment: Thats what I usually do always. I just wanted to make sure I wan't too paranoid.